# slick joins with function inputs

Tags: function, scala, join, input, slick

How is it possible to use inputs from the function and joins in slick

example

```
def query (coffeID : int) = DBAction { implicit rs =>
val implicitInnerJoin = for {
      c <- coffees
      s <- suppliers if ((c.supID === s.id ) && (c.cofID === coffeeID))
  } yield (c.name, s.name)
```

-- edit typo with ====

Comment: Int not int. Also === not =.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `===`

```
def query (coffeID : int) = DBAction { implicit rs =>
    val query = for {
        c <- coffees
        s <- suppliers if (c.supID === s.id) && (c.cofID === coffeeID)
    } yield (c.name, s.name)
    query.list
}
```

Comment: Sorry, typo. I did use `===` But nothing queries. I checked that it was a record of coffee table